# What exactly do DerivativeFilter and RidgeFilter do with the scale parameter?

Tags: image-processing, filtering, implementation-details, smoothing

Both [`DerivativeFilter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DerivativeFilter.html) and [`RidgeFilter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RidgeFilter.html) take an optional parameter `σ` to indicate the scale of derivatives being used. I would like to reproduce an algorithm I've been working on in another language, so I need to figure out what exactly these functions do with that parameter. However, the docs aren't giving much away. We have this from `DerivativeFilter`:

> [...] computes the derivative at a Gaussian scale of standard deviation `σ`.

> Image derivatives are susceptible to noise. To counteract this effect, you can regularize the image or data by a Gaussian kernel of standard deviation `σ`. The default value is `σ = 0`.

And this from `RidgeFilter`:

> [...] uses the specified ridge scale `σ`.

> In `RidgeFilter[image, σ]`, `σ` is the scale of the ridges that is used to compute the derivatives in the Hessian. By default, `σ = 1` is used.

I believe that the exact effect of `σ` is the same in both functions, because the docs of `DerivativeFilter` contain a reimplementation of `RidgeFilter`. It doesn't exactly match the outputs of `RidgeFilter`, but we can fix that by adding a simple `Clip`:

```
ridgeFilter[img_, σ_: 1] := Module[
  {data = ImageData[img], Lxx, Lxy, Lyy},
  {Lxx, Lxy, Lyy} = 
    DerivativeFilter[data, {{0, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}}, σ];
    Image[
      Clip[Chop[σ^(3/2)/2 (Sqrt[(Lxx - Lyy)^2 + 4 Lxy^2] - Lxx - Lyy)], {0, ∞}]
    ]
]
```

The results of this are identical (except for small numerical errors) to `RidgeFilter` and this just passes the `σ` through to `DerivativeFilter`.

Nevertheless, combining the information from the two pages of the docs, I still can't tell what exactly the functions are doing. It sounds to me like they simply run a [`GaussianFilter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GaussianFilter.html) over the image first. I can obtain results at the same scale by using `2 σ` as the radius of the Gaussian filter, but then I still get a lot of small scale artefacts that are missing when I use `DerivativeFilter` or `RidgeFilter` directly:

```
img = ColorConvert[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], "Grayscale"]
σ = 10;
ImageAssemble @ {
  ImageAdjust @ DerivativeFilter[img, {1, 1}, σ], 
  ImageAdjust @ DerivativeFilter[GaussianFilter[img, 2 σ], {1, 1}]
}
```

Results in:

[image: filtered image]

I'm actually completely baffled that I need to *double* `σ` (instead of halving it) since the docs for `GaussianFilter` call this parameter the *radius* `r` and they even say explicitly:

> `GaussianFilter[image, r]` uses `r = σ/2`.

All of this seems highly confusing, and there must be more to it than simply smoothing the input up front.

What exactly is the magic behind this `σ` parameter in `DerivativeFilter` (and by extension `RidgeFilter`)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`DerivativeFilter` calculates two sequential convolutions of original image with one-dimesional gaussian kernels.
First with vertical kernel and then with horizontal one.

Parameter `sigma` defines the standard deviation of the gaussian distribution which is used
to calculate each one-dimensional kernel.

Here is a code which reproduces `DerivativeFilter` using `ImageConvolve`:

```
mockupDerivativeFilter[image_, {verticalDerivativeOrder_, horizontalDerivativeOrder_}, sigma_] := Module[
    {verticalKernel, horizontalKernel, verticallyFilteredImage},

    verticalKernel = Transpose[{gaussianDerivativeKernel[verticalDerivativeOrder, sigma]}];
    horizontalKernel = {gaussianDerivativeKernel[horizontalDerivativeOrder, sigma]};

    verticallyFilteredImage = ImageConvolve[
        image,
        verticalKernel,
        Padding->"Fixed"
        ];

    ImageConvolve[
        verticallyFilteredImage,
        horizontalKernel,
        Padding->"Fixed"
        ]
    ];

gaussianDerivativeKernel[derivativeOrder_Integer, sigma_] := Module[
    {xvar, radius},
    radius =  Ceiling[1.0 + 6.23 sigma];
    Table[ N[D[1/(Sqrt[2 Pi] sigma) Exp[-xvar^2/(2 sigma^2)], {xvar, derivativeOrder}] /. xvar->x] , {x, -radius, radius}]
    ];

img = Image[ColorConvert[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], "Grayscale"], "Real32"];

referenceImage = ImageAdjust@DerivativeFilter[img, {1, 1}, 10];

mockupImage = ImageAdjust@mockupDerivativeFilter[img, {1, 1}, 10];

{referenceImage, mockupImage, referenceImage - mockupImage}
```

The function `GaussianFilter[image, r]` indeed uses standard deviation `sigma=r/2`.
The corresponding help page seems to be corrected in Mathematica 11.